# Swift : JSONSerialization.jsonObject not working for json into json

Tags: swift, xcode, json-serialization

I am using this code for geting json data from url:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
 guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

 do {           
   let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:String]
   completion(json)              
 } catch _ as NSError {
   completion(nil)
 }
}).resume()
```

If my json is `{"error":"true","message":"no"}` it works fine

But if i use json into json, it not works :

```
{"error":"true","message":"no","state":{"id":"1","name":"empty"}}
```

Comment: a JSON object is not a string, as you have declared [String: String]. Try as [String: Any]. You should use the Swift 4 Codable protocol for JSON serialisation.

Comment: @Scriptable and how i can get json and convert to string ? before i use Any, i cant get with code : result!["error"]!

Comment: @Scriptable i change my code to result!["error"]! as! String and work fine. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `as! [String:String]` you are saying that all values in the dictionary will be of String type, but the nested JSON related to the state key is obviously not a String

use  `as? [String: Any]` and then cast your other properties as needed. `result["error"] as String`

Using this method it makes getting the nested data more difficult than it needs to be:

```
if let state = result["state"] as? [String: String] {
    let name = state["name"]
    let value = state["value"]
}
```

Notes

1. When using Swift 4 or greater you should be using the Codable Protocol
2. You should not be force unwrapping, use conditional unwrapping (`as? [String: Any]`)

**EDIT:**

An example of how you can do this using Codable and how it is used.

**Playground code**

```
// you dont need this part, I am not making network request
let jsonData = """
{"error":"true","message":"no","state":{"id":"1","name":"empty"}}
""".data(using: .utf8)

struct ErrorState: Codable
{
    let id: String
    let name: String
}

struct ErrorResponse: Codable
{
    let error: String
    let message: String
    let state: ErrorState
}

guard let data = jsonData else { fatalError() }

let errorResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ErrorResponse.self, from: data)
print(errorResponse?.state.name)
```

Comment: Thank you, by use Any i can get data result!["error"]! as! String. but how i can get child of state like : result!["state"]["name"]! as! String

Answer (score 0):

You should use Codable protocol like this

```
 var json = [String:Any]()

    struct List : Decodable {

        let error : String
        let message : String

        private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case name = "error", score = "message" }

    }


    var list = [List]()

    let jsonString = """

                      {"error" : "true", "message" : "no"}

                     """

    let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

    do {
        list = try JSONDecoder().decode([List].self, from: data)
        let error = list.object(forKey: "error") as? String ?? ""
        print(error)
    } 
   catch { print(error) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this code.This Code should be works for your json Response.

```
let error = json["error"]! as! NSString
print(error) // it prints true

let message = json["message"]! as! NSString
print(message) // it prints no

guard let state = json["state"] as? [String: String],

let id = state["id"],      
let name = state["name"]

else  {
  return
}

print(id)  // it prints 1
print(name) // it prints empty
```

If any other questions please comment me!